# What does large in too large for worry mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, adjectives, vocabulary, quotes

What does *large* mean in this quote which is extracted from this poem [Promise yourself](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/189796-promise-yourself-to-be-so-strong-that-nothing-can-disturb)?

> Promise to be too large for worry, too noble for anger, too strong for fear, and too happy to permit trouble to press on you.

Comment: It's kind of meaningless, in a poetic way.

Comment: Magnanimous? Mature? Serene? Context probably makes it more obvious.

Comment: I have added the context in the question?

Comment: “Large” in this context means not petty, not worried about small things.

Comment: Oh, it makes sense. Thank you.

Comment: It's possibly related to the sense of "big" as magnanimous or generous: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big